# How to extend interface with generics in Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Let's say I have an interface like the below:

```
interface IProps<T> {
   property: T
}
```

How can extend the above interface, something like below,

```
interface IPropChild<U> extends IProps {
       propertyChild: U
   }
```

I know that the above syntax is wrong. Can you provide the right way to accomplish it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to accomplish?  Is `U` completely independent of `T`?  So then does `interface PropChild<T, U> extends IProps<T> {propertyChild: U}` meet your needs? If not, then please elaborate on what's missing.

Answer (score 4):

You can accept two generic type parameters and forward one to the interface that you extend:

```ts
interface Props<T> {
  property: T;
}

declare const props1: Props<string>;
props1.property; // string

// Forward the generic parameter T to the generic interface that it extends:
interface Extended<T, U> extends Props<T> {
  another: U;
}

declare const props2: Extended<string, number>;
props2.property; // string
props2.another; // number
```

Or, make the base interface generic type fixed when using the extending interface:

```ts
// Only use one generic parameter and decide in advance that
// this interface will always use `string` for the base interface:
interface ExtendedAndPropertyIsString<U> extends Props<string> {
  another: U;
}

declare const props3: ExtendedAndPropertyIsString<number>;
props2.property; // string
props2.another; // number
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAFQD5kBvAWAChlktMtowBPALmQIG4qBfKqgEwgIANnCgoEGEDjC16OAIxt02fDKigA5kS6U6qhQDp9DKMw7IA9JeTqtfSteQAxDFADuY-sjAALFJoQINDACLRicAC2EJBQ7D4YPv7IgcEaYaCx8EhJcLLAshAAHpAg-DgsVJnQ2SgAoiVBgvyEADTIAKokxaXlaPKEJBTUyHAgGH7QbB26vJQCQqLiyJLSsiY4AExsDb0QLXYgmu0gAK6RAEbQOlQbm8b0jEwWToeat-L3YxP+UC82Z0u0AcTgA8iBhExkKccCgpAEgiEwlgItFYqMyshBAhgIJkKBRvwAG5jHJ+PJUJx+YA4fHgGqIFDuYDCYSjYSeJi0mEoAAGb15yBgbiSKAucFhdKyjMqlGqsEZyF2TX2AEEyipTMwAJI4ADKYA0RzwXWQPSatM1akNWiGVBo30mUGmswc2KWEikMjkqgAzDtGmU1RrHmYmLqDUbNHhAVcoDc9J8Htgnv9bDajh9VF9xk607HoEA)